# How to save fetched html content to database in apache nutch?

Tags: java, apache, web-scraping, nutch, information-retrieval

I'm using 1.8 version of apache nutch. I want to save crawled HTML content to postgre database to do this, I modify `FetcherThread.java` class as below.

```
  case ProtocolStatus.SUCCESS: // got a page
  pstatus = output(fit.url, fit.datum, content, status,
  CrawlDatum.STATUS_FETCH_SUCCESS, fit.outlinkDepth);
  updateStatus(content.getContent().length);              
  /*Added My code Here*/
```

But I want to use plug-in system instead of directly modifying FetcherThread class. To use plug-in system which extension points I need to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a custom plugin and implement an extension of [org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexWriter](https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/nutch/indexer/IndexWriter.java) to send the documents to 
Postgres as part of the indexing step. You'll need to index the raw content which requires [NUTCH-2032](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-2032) - this is in Nutch 1.11 so you will need to upgrade your version of Nutch.

Alternatively you could write a custom MapReduce job which would take a segments as input, read the content and send it to your DB in the reduce step.